# How to make if statements on postgresql json field elements inside a django template

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I am having a hard time checking if a json field contains certain variable value in django template language.

This is my model:

```
from django.db.models import JSONField

class Widget(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    endpoint = models.CharField(max_length=512)  # "/data/id"
    type = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="line-graph")
    settings = JSONField(default=dict)
```

This is how I insert data to this model:

```
widget, created = Widget.objects.get_or_create(
    user=request.user,
    endpoint=endpoint,
)
widget.type = type_
widget.settings = {
    "code": "",
    "dashboard": dashboard.id,
    "position": "top",
    "params": "per=m&len=1"
}
```

However, when I do this in the template it fails:

```
{% if widget.setttings.position == "top" %}
```

This does not fail, on the other hand:

```
{% with widget.settings.position as pos %}
    {% if pos == "top" %}
```

and by "fail" I mean it doesn't pass the condition.

Am I doing something wrong?

- Django version: 3.2
- Python version: 3.8
- PostgreSQL version: 12.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3x 't' here:

```
{% if widget.setttings.position == "top" %}
```

Comment: oh God, you are right. I couldn't see that, and now I am embarrassed. Should I delete the question? It is stupid.

Comment: @xpanta no, it's ok to leave question like that :) It happens to all of us.